# HttpClient return json response on localhost when application live on server it's return html

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I'm calling API using HttpClient below code running fine on localhost but when it's live on server it's return html response.

**here is the code i'm using**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> getPost()
{
    string url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/Bg9DwFYHARK/?__a=1";
    HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    var Response = await _client.GetAsync(url);
    if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var Result = Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        //here in **Result** i've received html instead of json or when i received html instead 
        of json got error on DeserializeObject.
        var Jsonresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<post>(Result);

        return Json(new { isValid = false, error = "post found", obj = Jsonresult }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { isValid = false, error = "post not found" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the LIVE server is blocking the call, are you using a proxy that you need to bypass?

Comment: If you can post the HTML you're getting from the live server? it maybe an error.

Answer (score 0):

This method response is JSON.

```
string uri = "https://www.instagram.com/p/Bg9DwFYHARK/?__a=1";
    private static async Task<ActionResult> getPost(string uri)
    {
       var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
        if (webRequest == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webRequest.UserAgent = "Nothing";

        using (var s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
            {
               // var contributorsAsJson = sr.ReadToEnd();
                var contributors = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Create a list >(contributorsAsJson);
               // contributors.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                return contributors;
            }
        }
    }
```

I get out put is:

```
{"graphql":{"shortcode_media":{"__typename":"GraphImage","id":"1746568728937235530","shortcode":"Bg9DwFYHARK","dimensions":{"height":1080,"width":1080},"gating_info":null,"fact_check_overall_rating":null,"fact_check_information":null,"sensitivity_friction_info":null,"media_overlay_info":null,"media_preview":"ACoqytpjBOM+tQs6t07nvxwOn4889q2TDuGKzrfT2kkKtkBDz7j2PT0/OlpuUm7cvQqrbSS/cBb6D/IqI8DHfvXZiVI12qpBA+7xwPr0/WueMXm3LMBx94jryf0PrSTdwaVrlSKMsKd5ZrYji7n8B/8AWp3k+wp3ILSKT0FBkW2YM/AcEZ9xz+o4+uBVgyBSB26VDcWgnYFuVUEbfr3B9Qarl0HcRrgqQWVlX5snjIBxgsOw9fTFR2xEu+QdHbj6DgH8earPayvuUuXXHTGC2OgZv5461pQRGKNY+PlABx69/wBamKvuVJ9iMgikqwy4qPZSasJambblpm3dlP5n69x/9atgetZ1h/qV/H+ZrQHQfhWl7tk2JqY7bQT6UtRvTAN2aZUSnn8am2L6D8qdk9xbH//Z","display_url":"https://instagram.fcok6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/29400587_173904939930435_4131401846013034496_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fcok6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=103&_nc_ohc=cgtRDraKPGoAX_a9AvI&oh=fc8640215bbe4a5003bbaf694113951c&oe=5F2FFE5A","display_resources":[{"src":"https://instagram.fcok6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/29400587_173904939930435_4131401846013034496_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fcok6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=103&_nc_ohc=cgtRDraKPGoAX_a9AvI&oh=e971123fdc4eb19abe4a96b35195dd9f&oe=5F30CFBD","config_width":640,"config_height":640},{"src":"https://instagram.fcok6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s750x750/29400587_173904939930435_4131401846013034496_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fcok6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=103&_nc_ohc=cgtRDraKPGoAX_a9AvI&oh=33fe7c336ecff4205e161452adfc7ecf&oe=5F31703D","config_width":750,"config_height":750},{"src":"https://instagram.fcok6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/29400587_173904939930435_4131401846013034496_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fcok6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=103&_nc_ohc=cgtRDraKPGoAX_a9AvI&oh=fc8640215bbe4a5003bbaf694113951c&oe=5F2FFE5A","config_width":1080,"config_height":1080}],"accessibility_caption":"Photo by Ateeq Khalil in Salt N Pepper Liberty. Image may contain: 1 person","is_video":false,"tracking_token":"eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjo1LCJwYXlsb2FkIjp7ImlzX2FuYWx5dGljc190cmFja2VkIjp0cnVlLCJ1dWlkIjoiZWQ2ZjUxNTZjMjc5NDU5MzlmMmQ1MTQzZDBhZmIyYjYxNzQ2NTY4NzI4OTM3MjM1NTMwIn0sInNpZ25hdHVyZSI6IiJ9","edge_media_to_tagged_user":{"edges":[]},"edge_media_to_caption":{"edges":[]},"caption_is_edited":false,"has_ranked_comments":false,"edge_media_to_parent_comment":{"count":0,"page_info":{"has_next_page":false,"end_cursor":null},"edges":[]},"edge_media_to_hoisted_comment":{"edges":[]},"edge_media_preview_comment":{"count":0,"edges":[]},"comments_disabled":false,"commenting_disabled_for_viewer":false,"taken_at_timestamp":1522427239,"edge_media_preview_like":{"count":19,"edges":[]},"edge_media_to_sponsor_user":{"edges":[]},"location":{"id":"1730525857251432","has_public_page":true,"name":"Salt N Pepper Liberty","slug":"salt-n-pepper-liberty","address_json":"{\"street_address\": \"48 Commercial Zone Liberty Market, Gulberg III\\u060c\", \"zip_code\": \"\", \"city_name\": \"Lahore, Pakistan\", \"region_name\": \"\", \"country_code\": \"PK\", \"exact_city_match\": false, \"exact_region_match\": false, \"exact_country_match\": false}"},"viewer_has_liked":false,"viewer_has_saved":false,"viewer_has_saved_to_collection":false,"viewer_in_photo_of_you":false,"viewer_can_reshare":true,"owner":{"id":"5394358177","is_verified":false,"profile_pic_url":"https://instagram.fcok6-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/29402856_149619235868663_6235876322871083008_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fcok6-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=gSyry9Wj5UkAX_bQlzD&oh=bdc6a6b82077c8e461aedbaffa7e49db&oe=5F32308B","username":"ateeq.khalil","blocked_by_viewer":false,"restricted_by_viewer":null,"followed_by_viewer":false,"full_name":"Ateeq Khalil","has_blocked_viewer":false,"is_private":false,"is_unpublished":false,"requested_by_viewer":false,"edge_owner_to_timeline_media":{"count":7},"edge_followed_by":{"count":175}},"is_ad":false,"edge_web_media_to_related_media":{"edges":[]},"edge_related_profiles":{"edges":[]}}}}
```

Comment: same issue !!!! also your code working on localhost but not work on live server. on live server it's always goes in else condition.

Comment: Nothing changed after implementing this.
@Bibin there is any thing i need to add or change in web.config or Global.asax ?

Comment: @M.Ateeqkhalil first you publish the code and host on IIS.it's working